# Java hashmap - key based on two objects of different type

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to write a Java class to count the occurrence of some rules(for each rueleId) based on the associated timestamp.

For example,

Input:

```
{"ruleId": "1", "timestamp":"Thu Jun 18 16:25:56 PDT 2015"}
{"ruleId": "1", "timestamp":"Thu Jun 18 16:25:56 PDT 2015"}
{"ruleId": "2", "timestamp":"Thu Jun 18 16:25:56 PDT 2015"}
{"ruleId": "2", "timestamp":"Thu Jun 18 16:25:56 PDT 2015"}
{"ruleId": "2", "timestamp":"Thu Jun 18 16:27:56 PDT 2015"}
```

Output:

```
timestamp: "Thu Jun 18 16:25:56 PDT 2015", ruleId: "1", count: 2
timestamp: "Thu Jun 18 16:25:56 PDT 2015", ruleId: "2", count: 2
timestamp: "Thu Jun 18 16:27:56 PDT 2015", ruleId: "2", count: 1
```

I suppose I can make use of a HashMap.

Key here I think is based on both ruleId(type : String) and timestamp(type : Calendar) with value being the count.

How can I have a key based on two different objects?
Is my approach wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a *composite key*:

```
public final class CompositeKey {
    private final String ruleType;
    private final Calendar timeStamp;

    public CompositeKey(String ruleType, Calendar timeStamp) {
        this.ruleType = Objects.requireNonNull(ruleType);
        this.timeStamp = (Calendar) Objects.requireNonNull(timeStamp).clone();
    }

    public String ruleType() { return ruleType; }
    public Calendar timeStamp() { return (Calendar) timeStamp.clone(); }

    @Override public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
        CompositeKey other = (CompositeKey) obj;
        return Objects.equals(ruleType, other.ruleType) && Objects.equals(timeStamp, other.timeStamp);
    }

    @Override public int hashCode() { return Objects.hash(ruleType, timeStamp); }
}
```

It is essential that objects cannot be modified when being used as a key in a `HashMap`. Therefore it must be immutable. The class above achieves that goal by being final, not providing setters, and cloning the timestamp (as `Calendar` is not immutable).

Another very important thing is that key classes must provide proper `equals` and `hashCode` methods.

With that class in place, you can use it in a `HashMap`:

```
String ruleType = ...
Calendar timeStamp = ...
CompositeKey key = new CompositeKey(ruleType, timeStamp);
Object value = ...

Map<CompositeKey, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(key, value);
```

Answer (score 2):

A `HashMap` only has one key type. That is just the way it is.

So you have two options.

Generate a key string that acts as Key for the HashMap. In your case that is something that can be done easily and it might just be all you need. You could generate something like `"time:" + timeStamp.toString() + "-rule:" + ruleId` and use that as a key. It will do the trick in your case.

The second method is a little more complex but better suited if you want to separate the values again that you used in the key or if you got more complex values as key. The idea is to create a new class that acts as carrier for your key values.

The important thing for this second idea is that you overwrite the `hashCode` and the `equals` function of your carrier object to get it to work properly with the `HashMap`.

Basically you need something like this:

```
public class Carrier {
    private final Calendar timestamp;
    private final String ruleId;

    public Carrier(Calendar timestamp, String ruleId) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.ruleId = ruleId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 1;
        hash = hash * 17 + timestamp.hashCode();
        hash = hash * 17 + ruleId.hashCode();
        return hash;
    }

    @Override 
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceOf Carrier) {
            return false;
        }

        Carrier other = (Carrier) obj;
        return Objects.equals(ruleId, other.ruleId) && Objects.equals(timestamp, other.timestamp);
    }
}
```